# Laravel - Get only attributes data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am currently working on Laravel 6.13. I am using eloquent join to fetch the data from multiple tables.

Here is my working code:

```
    $ToGetDefaultAddress = TbPersonaddress::join('tb_cities AS TbCitie','TbCitie.n_CityId_PK', '=', 'tb_personaddresses.n_CityId_FK')
                                            ->join('tb_counties AS TbCountie','TbCountie.n_CountyId_PK', '=', 'tb_personaddresses.n_CountyId_FK')
                                            ->join('tb_states AS TbState', 'TbState.n_StateId_PK','=' ,'tb_personaddresses.n_StateId_FK')
                                            ->select('tb_personaddresses.n_PersonAddressesId_PK','tb_personaddresses.n_PersonId_FK',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_AddressTypeCode','tb_personaddresses.s_HouseNo',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_HouseDirection1','tb_personaddresses.s_StreetName',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_HouseType','tb_personaddresses.s_HouseDirection2',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_AddressLine1','tb_personaddresses.s_AddressLine2',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_AddressLine3','tb_personaddresses.s_AddressLine4',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.n_CountyId_FK','tb_personaddresses.n_CityId_FK',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.n_StateId_FK','tb_personaddresses.n_CountryId_FK',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_PostalCode','tb_personaddresses.n_Zipcodes_FK',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_Latitude','tb_personaddresses.s_Longitude',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_CountryName','tb_personaddresses.s_Description',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.d_EffectiveDateFrom','tb_personaddresses.d_EffectiveDateTo',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.s_IsDefaultAddress','tb_personaddresses.n_CreatedUser',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.d_CreatedDate','tb_personaddresses.n_UpdatedUser',
                                            'tb_personaddresses.d_UpdatedDate','tb_personaddresses.n_EditVersion',
                                            'TbCitie.s_CityCode','TbCitie.s_CityName','TbCountie.s_CountyCode',
                                            'TbCountie.s_CountyName','TbState.s_StateCode','TbState.s_StateName')->first();
```

I checked using dd() for output. [image]I want to get only attributes data as specified in image. How can I get those ?

Tried solutions from following link:
[Laravel Getting attributes data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42897045/laravel-getting-attributes-data)

But those are not working.

Here's what I tried from link after above code:

```
 $DefaultAddress = $ToGetDefaultAddress->all()->toArray();                                            
 dd(":::::::::::To get default address::::::::",$DefaultAddress);
```

But it returns blank output.

Comment: You can call `->toArray()` after `->first()`, but you'll lose all functionality in `TbPersonaddress`. Note: if you're returning this data via JSON, everything but the attributes will automatically be stripped when casting to JSON. You need to clarify why you only want the attributes/what you want to do with this data/why you think you don't need everything else.

Comment: you can use `->getAttributes()` too.

Comment: You need to tell us more than `But those are not working`.  Why not? What happens?  The answer you linked to *is* the answer to the question you have asked - if yours is somehow different, you need to explain why.

Comment: @Don'tPanic updated the same

Comment: [`all()` is a query method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models), the same as `first()`, which you are already using.  Using both does not make sense and won't work.  If you want the *first* result, use `first()`.  If you want *all* results, use `all()`.  Do not use both.  Whichever you chose, to convert the model or collection, respectively, to an array, use `toArray()`.

Comment: This really is a duplicate of the question you linked to, I suggest closing it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You should chain the `toArray()` function at the end of your database call to get only the attributes (and any loaded relations).